# Azure Function to Check user access to tenants

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

I need help making making this function app work Please.

I need this function to check user ID  against 5 tenants for yes or No access.

Code

```
param($req, $res)

# extract input parameters from the request

$email = $req.params.email
$Id = $req.params.Id

$tenant1 = $req.params.tenant1
$tenant2 = $req.params.tenant2
$tenant3 = $req.params.tenant3
$tenant4 = $req.params.tenant4
$tenant5 = $req.params.tenant5

# perform user and access validation

$approved = $true
$accessType = "Standard"
$message = ""

if ($email -ne "user@example.com") {
  $approved = $false
  $message = "User account does not exist"
}

elseif ($Id -ne "B17283") {
  $approved = $false
  $message = "User is not a member of the tenant"
}


# generate response

$tenantApprovals = @()
if ($tenant1) {
  $tenantApproval = [ordered]@{
    Tenant = $tenant1
    AccessApprovalStatus = $approved ? "Yes" : "No"
    AccessType = $accessType
    Message = $message
  }

  $tenantApprovals += $tenantApproval
}

if ($tenant2) {
  $tenantApproval = [ordered]@{
    Tenant = $tenant2
    AccessApprovalStatus = $approved ? "Yes" : "No"
    AccessType = $accessType
    Message = $message
  }

  $tenantApprovals += $tenantApproval
}


if ($tenant3) {

  $tenantApproval = [ordered]@{
    Tenant = $tenant3
    AccessApprovalStatus = $approved ? "Yes" : "No"
    AccessType = $accessType
    Message = $message
  }

  $tenantApprovals += $tenantApproval
}

if ($tenant4) {
  $tenantApproval = [ordered]@{
    Tenant = $tenant4
    AccessApprovalStatus = $approved ? "Yes" : "No"
    AccessType = $accessType
    Message = $message
  }

  $tenantApprovals += $tenantApproval
}

 
if ($tenant5) {
  $tenantApproval = [ordered]@{
    Tenant = $tenant5
    AccessApprovalStatus = $approved ? "Yes" : "No"
    AccessType = $accessType
    Message = $message
  }

  $tenantApprovals += $tenantApproval
}

$body = @{
  Result = $tenantApprovals
} | ConvertTo-Json

 
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
  StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the user belongs to multiple tenants requires cross-tenant feature.

As stated in this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1195367/how-to-check-a-user-belongs-to-multiple-azure-ad-t) and, using the external identities and access settings in cross-tenant managed by Azure AD Organizations.

Because the user can be guest also, only users of that same tenant can have the privileges to retrieve the other user's information.

For checking the user belongs to current logged in tenant or you have to login to specific tenant to which you're checking about the user, the PowerShell Code you can use in your Azure Function is:

```
$usertenant = "<UserEmail/PrinicpalName>.onmicrosoft.com" 
Connect-AzureAD -TenantDomain  $usertenant  
$tenantData = Get-AzureADTenantDetail  
$tenantId = $tenant.ObjectId 
Write-Host "Tenant ID: $tenantId"  
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $tenantId  
$user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Samson'"  
if (!$user) 
{ 
     Write-Host "User not available in the given tenant" 
} 
else 
{
     Write-Host "User available in the given tenant" 
}
```